# MySQL stripping $number characters from field on update

Tags: mysql

I am so stumped by this. I have gone all the way down to the command line to rule out our application framework, PHP etc.

```
UPDATE booking 
    SET usages = 'Rate: $450 +20% for the first hour, $225 +20% each additional hour, $300 +20% for 30 min pickup' 
WHERE id = 88979"
```

When I do a SELECT to get it back:

```
Rate: 50 +20% for the first hour, 25 +20% each additional hour, 00 +20% for 30 min pickup
```

So MySQL is stripping **$4**, **$2**, and **$3** from the string. Is it mistaking them for variables?

Do I need to escape the **$**?

Comment: No. it should be fine. Can you show how you pass data on data

Comment: I just used "UPDATE booking SET usages = 'Rate: \$450 +20% for the first hour, \$225 +20% each additional hour, \$300 +20% for 30 min pickup' WHERE id = 88979" and it worked. So MySQL is assuming the $4 etc are parameters. 

Wondering if this is a setting that can be turned off?

Comment: what language, what database api

Comment: Are you doing this from the command line? From phpMyAdmin? From inside a PHP script???

Comment: First from PHP, then phpMyAdmin, then CLI to check. On local server it's fine, on production server the issue is occurring, which leads me to think it's a setting??

Comment: Please post the exact context in which you call the statement, whether it's in PHP, a shell script or anything else. We have to see how the code is implemented that executes the statement - MySQL itself won't alter `$` but the shell might.

Comment: CLI:

mysql -e "UPDATE booking_casting SET message = 'Rate: $450 +20% for the first hour, $225 +20% each additional hour, $300 +20% for 30 min pickup' WHERE id = 332"

Result:

"Rate: 50 +20% for the first hour, 25 +20% each additional hour, 00 +20% for 30 min pickup"

Comment: Could also be something to do with special character encoding?

https://gist.github.com/schmoove/93f4c13560a8170a61e20ff9791e10e2